# Navigation float - resize break

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, css-float, navigationbar

Ok, I I have a navigation in which four elements floating left,and other two floating to the right.The whole navigation is made in percentage,in order to be responsive.
But,on window resize,elements that float right "catch up" elements that float left,and then go under them.And I am very frustrated already,because I can't figure out what is going on.

Here it is: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7cwpn95/).Not perfect, but you can see what's going on.

```
        <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="logo" href="home.html" title="Back to Home Page"></a>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="menu-button"></div><!-- end of menu-button -->
                <ul class="flexnav" data-breakpoint="800">
                    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link2222</a></li>
                    <li><a class="service" href="#">Do Your Homework</a></li>
                    <li><a id="circle" href="#">My Homework</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Homework Login</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div><!-- end of navigation --> 
    </div><!-- end of wrapper -->
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper { max-width: 1140px; margin: 0 auto; }

.navigation {
    width: 64.91228%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    left:10.35087%;
}
.flexnav {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    font-family: "Fauna One", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

    .flexnav:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both; 
    }

    .flexnav>li {
        float: left;
    }

    .flexnav li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin:6px 2.7027027% 0 0;
        padding:0 2.7027027% 0 0;
        border-right:2px solid #4d4e4f; 
    }

        /* The links */
        .flexnav li a {
            /* Layout */
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            z-index: 2;
            padding:0 0 0 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            /* Typography */
            font-size: 1em;
            color: #ff000;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .flexnav li:nth-child(3) {
            border:none;
            margin:6px 0 0 0;
        }
        .flexnav li:nth-child(4) {
            border:none;
            margin-right:0;
            padding-right:0;
        }
        .flexnav li:nth-child(5) {
            float:right;
            border-right:none;
            margin:10px 0 0 0;
            padding:0 0 0 0;
        }
        .flexnav li:nth-child(6) {
            float:right;
            border-right:none;
            margin:10px 2.04350691% 0 0;
            padding:0 2.04350691% 0 0;
        }
        .flexnav li:nth-child(5) a {
            border-right:none;
            padding-bottom:3px;
            font-size:0.750em;
        }
        .flexnav li:nth-child(6) a {
            border-right:none;
            padding-bottom:3px;
            font-size:0.750em;
        }
        .flexnav li .service {
            max-width:141px;
            min-height:20px;
            position:relative;
            font-size:0.875em;
            margin:-3px 0 0 0;
            padding:6px 28px 0 10px;
            background-color:#000;
            border-radius:3px;
        }
```

What I want is that when left part comes to the right side, together continue to slide to the left.

Comment: You want to keep them on the same line?

Comment: Yes,and keep them in structure as it was.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after fiddling with this for an hour i got it to work.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/hm6m7c1y/)

There where a few things that made this possible.

css

```
.wrapper {
    /*Sets a scroll bar on the div when reaches minimal width*/
    overflow-x:auto;
    /*aligns UL elements center*/
    text-align:center;
    /*Makes sure that no element wraps to next line*/
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

js

```
//Creates a media query to make sure that no float will wrap
var navWidth = 0;
var buffer = 50;
//grabs the width of the all the ul elements
$('ul').each(function(){
    navWidth += $(this).width() + buffer;
});
//sets a media query to turn off float at the max width of the nav bar.
$('#style').html("@media (max-width:"+navWidth+"px) { .pull-right{ float: none; }}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,but I don't need scroll bar.It must reduce the width, until for example, 700px,then appears responsive menu...